# Python - pass variables from a subroutine to the main program

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to call a subroutine to gather data.  This is in a loop.  So each iteration I would like to write to an excel file.  I could just copy the subroutine into the main program, but would like a cleaner way to do this.  I have something like this:

```
#This creates my path and file name to open later
path = os.getcwd()
filetime = time.strftime("_%Y_%H_%M_%S", time.localtime()) 
fname = 'Test'
fext = '.csv'
fpath = path + '/' + fname + filetime + fext


#start of loop
for val1 in range(5):
    for val in range(6):
        #write some register with val1
        #write some register with val2
        subprocess.call("test.py", shell=True)
        #this subprosses does something that spits out data for 8 variables a through h

        #I would like to write that data into the path and file I created above
        data=open(fpath, 'a')
        #data.write('%.2f\n' % (cl))
        data.write('%i,%i,%i,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f,%.2f\n' % (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h))
        data.close()
```

## Now that I have the data written, would like to go through all iteration of loop and append the data into the file

Comment: why don't you just integrate it into one program ? calling python process from python is pointless.

Comment: I do not understand. Do you want to look into `import`?

Answer (score 0):

I could integrate it into main program. Done that already and it works fine. But, many lines of codes in subroutine.  More importantly, I would like to call other sub-process for this  simple high level exec.  Even having some simple logic in the main exec to call several other sub routines that could potentially pass data.  In my mind, this would simplify by making a high level exec instead of looking at 10k lines of code to debug in main program. This way I could debug each subroutine individually.  Everyone has their own style to code.  Maybe this isn't traditional way to do this, but wanted to know if it could be done or not.